# Can I insert a Data Extension Record across different Business Unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have an automation that can grab data from enhanced FTP. This part is done already.

However, I'm puzzling on how can I insert data from parent BU's data extension to child BU's to data extension? You can assume they have the same column settings.

Comment: are you inserting records from FTP? for different BUs

Comment: based on  that Ftp Account you can insert records in different Business account

Comment: I just have parent BUs FTP A/C

Comment: you can insert records manually create one csv file then goto child Bu and open Target DE and insert records

Comment: If the task is in one-time basis, I can do it in this way. However I have 50 tables with nearly 1M records, and this task should perform every day.

Comment: Might have to import to a DE in the parent account BU, and then run a sql query to transfer the records to the child BU's data extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the data extension in the Parent BU as a shared data extension. You can write a query to copy data from it into the child BU DE.

Create a query in the Child BU which does this:

```
Select *
From ENT.ParentBU_DEName
```

Answer (score 0):

@PY Yick using Query you can achieve this one  try like this  write this in Child BU

```
select * from source DE where OYBAccountID='parent Bu'
```